# Simple RewriteRule question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This seems so simple, but I can't figure it out... I would like all requests to be rewritten to index.php (which will interpret the request) **apart from** 404.html which should be rewritten directly to 404.php.

The following code does work at rewriting everything to index.php, but 404.php never gets triggered.

I have left line 3 commented because I don't know what it does.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^404.html$ 404.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php  [QSA]
```

As you can see, my needs are very simple, but so is my brain! Please help!

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This line works fine on its own:

```
RewriteRule ^404.html$ 404.php
```

but when the other RewriteRule is introduced, everything gets forced through index.php - even 404.html...... (I tried changing the order too).

Comment: line three says 'the following rule only applies if the requested filename is not an existing file. (-f is a file, -d is a directory, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was driving me **MAD!** but I found the answer, for those who are getting confused like I was.

Look at line 4:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^404.html$ 404.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Taken from: [easymodrewrite](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/notes-last):

The [L] flag can have unexpected results if you are not clear on how the module behaves. Note that the following only applies when mod_rewrite is used in a .htaccess file. The [L] flag behaves exactly as expected when used in httpd.conf.

The L flag will tell Apache to stop processing the rewrite rules for that request. Now what is often unrealised is that it now makes a new request for the new, rewritten filename and begin processing the rewrite rules again.

---

Basically, you have to tell the second rule not to match existing files (404.php is a real file, not dynamic).

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can invert the result of a match with prepend it with `!`. So:

```
RewriteRule ^404\.html$ 404.php
RewriteRule !^404\.html$ index.php [QSA]
```

This will match any request that’s path is *not* matched by `^404\.html$`.

You might need to add the condition that is commented out:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^404\.html$ index.php [QSA]
```

Now this rule will only match if the request can additionally not be mapped onto an existing file.

Comment: I don't understand how this helps - I do want 404.html to be rewritten to 404.php ... and everything else to index.php with the requesnt as a query string.

Comment: hmm, using what you put, requesting 404.html still gets directed to index.php ... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Greg: I guess you need to extend the second rule not to match existing files. Because otherwise `404.php` will also be matched.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^404.html$ 404.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php  [QSA]
```

I believe the issue is that you are rewriting the URL to 404.php, then sending it to index.php. Putting [L] after the first rule will instruct the rewrite engine to not continue rewriting.